# Query multiple records between "Weeks" where no record in child table

Tags: ms-access, between

I am trying to determine the best method for how to handle this query using Access 2013.  I have a clients table that contains the following:

```
clientID    fName    lName    admissionDate    dischargeDate
1            John      Doe        05/06/2014       06/27/2014
2            Jane      Doe        04/24/2014       05/15/2014
3            Steven    Smith      05/15/2014       NULL/Empty
4            Chris     Davis      06/12/2014       NULL/Empty
```

Then there is a WeeklyProgressNotes table that is there for the person that is responsible for auditing the clients charts.  It does not contain the actual weeklyprogressnotes, it only contains a Yes/No field and a date field for the date the weeklyprogressnote was completed.  Like below:

```
noteID     completed     dateCompleted     clientID
1            yes              05/08/2014          1
2            yes              05/14/2014          1
3            yes              04/25/2014          2
```

I am creating a form that the auditor can open to determine what weeks she needs to check for each client to see if they have their weeklyprogressnotes completed that week.  The weeks run Mon - Sun and there will be no record in the WeeklyProgressNotes table if she has not yet checked and confirmed for that week.  So the form would basically look like this:

```
fName    lName       week              completed        date      clientID(hidden)
John      Doe       5/19/14-5/25/14    Checkbox          Null        1
John      Doe       5/26/14-6/1/14     Checkbox          Null        1
John      Doe       6/2/14-6/8/14      Checkbox          Null        1
John      Doe       6/9/14-6/15/14     Checkbox          Null        1
John      Doe       6/16/14-6/22/14    Checkbox          Null        1
John      Doe       6/23/14-6/29/14    Checkbox          Null        1
Jane      Doe       4/28/14-5/4/14     Checkbox          Null        2
```

and so on.......

I have thought about creating an SQL statement to select all of the clients and then creating a function that determines their admission date within the specific week and their discharge date withing the specific week and then create a loop with another SQL statement with a BETWEEN clause for all the weeks and determine if there is an entry in the WeeklyProgressNotes table or not.  If not then I would display out the above info.  I'm not sure if there is an easier, less search intensive way of doing it.  Maybe an SQL query that can cut done on some of the looping.

Answer (score 0):

The way I would address this problem, is to create a new table. Since you want to split up date time between addmission and discharge date into multiple rows, I think it would be best to split the client in multiple records in a table.

The following code creates a recordset based on your basic clients table. Afterwards it creates your temporary table (Here populated by only 2 fields due to a lack of time). When you loop through the recordset of your original table, you hold on each row and split the time between the addmission and dischargedate in blocks of one week.

Afterwards, once you have populated the table, it is easy to create a simple query based on this table and the table with the weeklyprogressnotes.

I hope my explanation was sufficient and please note that I have not tested the code yet. It will most likely require some tweaking on your behalf. Perhaps I can look at it later on if I've got some more time on my hands.

```
Sub showrecords()
Dim gvweek As String
Dim rs As Recordset
Dim rstemp As Recordset
Dim tdfNew As TableDef

gvweek = ""

Set tdfNew = CurrentDb.CreateTableDef("Tbl_Temporary")
With tdfNew
    .Fields.Append .CreateField("fName", dbText)
    .Fields.Append .CreateField("week", dbText)
End With

Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Clients")
With rs
    Do Until .EOF
        .MoveFirst
            Do Until DateAdd("dd", 7, ![admissionDate]) > ![dischargeDate]
                gvweek = ![admissionDate] & " - " & DateAdd("dd", 7, ![admissionDate])
                    Set rstemp = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Tbl_Temporary")
                        With rstemp
                            .AddNew
                            ![fName] = rs![fName]
                            ![week] = gvweek
                            .Update
                        End With
                    rstemp.Close
                    Set rstemp = Nothing
            Loop
        gvweek = ""
        .MoveNext
    Loop
End With

rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
DoCmd.DeleteObject acTable, "Tbl_Temporary"
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm working on implementing this.  My experience with VB style scripts has all been web design related and I have never created a temp table like this in Access.  I think that I have the brunt of the code that will sort through and create the temporary table with all the data.  Now I'm trying to figure out how to access that temp table and use its field values for my control source in my form.  Any additional thoughts or direction?  Thank you for your above response.  I found it very informative and a good learning experience as I have never attempted anything like this before in Access.

Comment: You can perhaps visually create the table and empty it each time once you are done with it programmatatically if that fits you better.
Be careful with that, if the form opens before the table is created you will definitely get errors. You are going to have to programmatically create your query if you are going to use this method. What you want to do is create an SQL string consisting of the info you want from your temporary table and your weeklyprogress table. Then afterwards you can open your form and set your query as the source code. Thank you, Hopefully my answer is sufficient!